# belongs_to, has_many

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, aplicação-web, crud

Olá pessoal tudo bom? Estou começando no Rails e obtive um probleminha para fazer uma aplicação web simples com:

- Cadastro de clientes (com nome e endereço)
- Cadastro de    colaboradores (só com nome)
- Cadastro de ordem de serviço (com a    data em que a O.S. foi
  aberta, o cliente desta O.S., texto com    problema relatado pelo
  cliente, o colaborador que foi ativado para    resolver o problema do
  cliente e um campo booleano para indicar se a    O.S. foi resolvida)

**Todas contendo o CRUD

Criei os Scaffolds

```
rails g scaffold Costumer name:string adress:string
rails g scaffold Employee name:string
```

Aqui que entra o porém. Criei o Scaffold assim para fazer a relação que existe:

`rails g scaffold OrderService date:datetime description:text Costumer:reference Employee:references`

Dei o `rake db:create db:migrate` para concretizar tudo no banco

Mas nao sei depois o que fazer, se usar o belongs_to, has_many...?

Answer (score 1):

No Active Record, as associações funcionam como conectores em memória dos objetos.

Existem diferentes tipos de associações: `belongs_to`, `has_many`, `has_one`, `has_many :through`, `has_one :through` e  `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Vou ilustrar para você as duas principais.

#### `has_many` e `belongs_to`

Quando se fala de banco de dados, o `has_many` essa indica uma associação um-pra-muitos (1:N). Por outro lado, o `belongs_to` é um relacionamento um-pra-um (1:1).

Para ilustrar, se uma ordem de serviço tem um cliente associado:

```
class ServiceOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service_orders
end
```

Veja que o outro lado da associação, `Customer`, indica um relacionamento com o `has_many`. É opcional que tenha `has_many` ali, pois ele só vai adicionar os *helper methods* da associação. Veja:

```
service_order = ServiceOrder.first
service_order.customer
#=> retorna o cliente associado
```

e também

```
customer = Customer.first
customer.service_orders
#=> retorna todas as ordens de serviço do cliente
```

Recomendo a leitura de [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) no guia oficial do Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Uma dica já que está começando é sempre que for fazer alguma coisa abre o rails guides e confere se tem alguma outra coisa que precisa fazer, tem praticamente tudo lá sobre o rails

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Comment: Olá @VitorC. Evite colocar _links_ na sua resposta. Pode colocá-los como complemento, mas deve sempre tentar postar código que ajude na resolução do problema.